# Cannot get date conversion to work VBA to SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, date, vba

I am currently working on a macro in excel that will upload to our sql server. I am getting a consistent error when it comes to the date column. SQL uses the YYYY-MM-DD format, and the excel sheet we get comes in the DD/MM/YYYY format. The spreadsheet is auto generated. Here is the code I'm currently using, I am getting the Date and time conversion failed error message whenever I try to run it.

```
   Do While Counter < RowNumber
        .AddNew
        .Fields("StoreNumber").Value = Cells(Counter, 1).Value
        .Fields("EmployeeID").Value = Cells(Counter, 2).Value
        .Fields("Name").Value = Cells(Counter, 3).Value
        .Fields("EmailAddress").Value = Cells(Counter, 4).Value
        .Fields("ServiceDate").Value = Cells(Counter, 5).Value = Format(Date, "YYYY-M-D")
        .Fields("Action").Value = Cells(Counter, 6).Value
        .Fields("Reason").Value = Cells(Counter, 7).Value
        .Fields("JobCode").Value = Cells(Counter, 8).Value
        .Fields("JobDescription").Value = Cells(Counter, 9).Value
        .Fields("BGC").Value = Cells(Counter, 11).Value
        .Fields("DispositionDate").Value = Date
        .Fields("DispositionTime").Value = Format(Time, "HH:MM:SS")
        .Fields("DispositionedBy").Value = "System"
        If Cells(Counter, 10).Value = "7. No Action" Then
            .Fields("Disposition").Value = "7.No Action"
        ElseIf Cells(Counter, 10).Value = "8. Exited in Error" Then
            .Fields("Disposition").Value = "8.Exited in Error"
        ElseIf Cells(Counter, 10).Value = "Executive- Do Not Hire" Then
            .Fields("Disposition").Value = "7.No Action"
        Else
            .Fields("Disposition").Value = "9.New Item"
        End If
        .Update
        Counter = Counter + 1
        Application.StatusBar = "Uploading: " & Counter & " of " & RowNumber
        DoEvents
    Loop
    .Close
End With
Application.StatusBar = False
PhoneHiringConn.Close
Set PhoneHiringRecord = Nothing
Set PhoneHiringConn = Nothing
```

I've tried everything and it just won't convert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Fields("ServiceDate").Value = Cells(Counter, 5).Value = Format(Date, "YYYY-M-D")
```

This is nonsense.

```
<something> = val1 = val2
```

Means that `val1=val2` will be evaluated first, which will be either `TRUE` or `FALSE`. You don't want a boolean, but rather a string that is a formatted date. To do this, use the value in your `Cells(Counter, 5)` range as the first parameter to your `Format()` function:

```
 .Fields("ServiceDate").Value = Format(Cells(Counter, 5).Value, "YYYY-M-D")
```